Как в redis python создать удаляющийся хэшсет?
Всем привет!
Мне нужно в redis создать хэшсет, который будет удаляться каждые 6 месяцев.
С обычными строками все работает, в python библиотеке redis для этого есть метод setex. Но что делать с хэшсетами?
В доке нет информации о таком методе, как hexpire или что-то вроде того

Ну, банально запускайте удаляющий python-скрипт раз в 6 месяцев, например?

@andreymal вы не поняли) сам redis предоставляет такой метод, но аналога нет в библиотеке redis-py для работы с БД redisА. Хотя должен быть. К тому же я специально пишу проект на redis, а не на другой БД, так как в нем это предусмотрено

Уже есть в версии 5.1 https://github.com/redis/redis-py/pull/3218

@andreymal действительно.. странно, у меня ошибка, что метода нет. Пойду обновлю модуль, хотя вроде у меня последняя версия.

А последняя это 5.0, версия 5.1 ещё в бете

@andreymal аа, ну понятно тогда) спасибо большое
